# Distributing Ruby along with application?

Tags: ruby, client, desktop-application, distribution

I have a simple desktop Ruby client which I would like to distribute to a small number of (technical and non-technical) people.

The client will run as a daemon, hence there is no GUI. I only need the client to run on OSX and Linux.

Is there a way that I can distribute a certain version of Ruby with the application and run my client using that version? How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it's probably prohibitively complicated. Ruby needs to be compiled for the platform you're running it on, so you would need to have access to all the different platforms you'd be distributing to and then compile against those, include all of them in your distribution, and detect at runtime the current platform and pick the correct binary. This whole process is excessive and error-prone. Further, these binaries are not necessarily very small, which will bloat your distributable.

So why not just point them to [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) for Windows, tell them they're set to go on OS X, and Ubuntu users are generally savvy enough that you can give them more complicated instructions, or, better yet, distribute your application as an Ubuntu package so Ruby gets installed as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Half an answer is that you don't need to distribute ruby to OSX users - ruby is already installed on OSX machines.  As long as your code works with Ruby 1.8.7, you are fine on a Mac.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that fact.

Comment: Pretty much this, and I'd point out that a lot of distributions of Linux have Ruby installed by default, too. `which ruby` should let you know. If you're looking to use the latest and greatest performance improvements and save a few keystrokes on hash syntax, this doesn't help, but if the OP is going after non-technical users this is probably the easiest route.

Comment: You don't need to distribute Ruby to OSX users, but a) what if the application requires 1.9.2, instead of whatever comes installed? And what if it requires gems? What if it even requires binary gems, which requires installation of XCode (several gigabytes download) before they can be compiled? That's a lot to ask of users.

Comment: This is a good question and i'm with Stian on this.  Working with less-technical front-end developers who use things such as Compass and SASS, and seeing the nightmare that version dependencies can be with Ruby, packaging up Ruby+Gems definitely has value.  I think although there are tools out there to aid this (e.g. RVM), sometimes it just makes it more complicated and things just become a mess.

Comment: No. This is a terrible answer. Never be this lazy and do this. You don't know when it breaks. This is just dying and getting your soul catched in dependency hell.