# Moving Ruby installation causes it to not function. How to get around this?

Tags: ruby

I would like to compile Ruby from source, install it, then move the installation somewhere else.

For example:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125$ ./configure --prefix=/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125
```

The problem is that it would seem the `--prefix` path is hardcoded in the Ruby binary.  When I move `/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125` to say `/opt/ruby-1.9.3-p125`, the hardcoded paths are present in the installed binaries and scripts.

After moving, I get an error:

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Why don't you just compile it with the actual prefix you're going to install it to?

Comment: I have an application that relies on ruby-1.9.  I want to package it precompiled with my application.  Of course, I will distribute the Ruby source with the application, per the license, but I don't have control over where the user will install the application.  Therefore, I would like to configure it in some way that it can be relocated.

Comment: On that note, please see [Distributing Ruby along with application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165216/distributing-ruby-along-with-application) for why that's not such a good idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Andrew.  My application is designed only for Linux x86_64 systems, so I'm not too worried about portability to other platforms.  I did find a solution in the answer below-

Comment: Maybe my answer needs to be accepted first? Anyway, solution is to pass --enable-load-relative to configure.

Comment: Maybe [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) could be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found that the solution is to use --enable-load-relative when running configure

So instead of:

```
./configure
```

Run:

```
./configure --enable-load-relative
```

Comment: Also see this post for a more thorough discussion:
http://yehudakatz.com/2012/06/

Comment: can you explain what you mean by configuring?